# Get access to HttpServletRequest within a custom AuthenticationProvider

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

How do I get access to HttpServletRequest within a custom AuthenticationProvider. I have tried doing this

```
RequestAttributes requestAttributes = RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();

HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) requestAttributes).getRequest();
String username = (String) httpReq.getAttribute("j_username");
```

OR

```
RequestAttributes requestAttributes = RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
HttpServletRequest httpReq = ((ServletRequestAttributes)RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest();

String username = (String) httpReq.getAttribute("j_username");
```

i am getting username null

but `RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();` returns `null`.

I want to reference the requestcontext, pass it in, or have Spring do its Magic so I can reference it.

I am also giving the RequestContextListener in my web.xml

```
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
```

I have searched the security forum but still havent found anything yet.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't those credentials be contained within the Authentication object? http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/AuthenticationProvider.html

Comment: Dardo is correct. I think you should probably look at some basic samples and read some of the documentation, then explain in more detail what you are trying to achieve, because I can't think of a valid reason for trying to access the username in this way.

Comment: The credentials will indeed be in the Authentication object. However, I'm also looking for a solution. I too need to access the request but for another reason. In my app the URL plays a role in the authentication. Any ideas on how to get it in this class?

Answer (score 9):

I just added the listener to my web.xml and RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes() returns the RequestAttributes instead of null.

```
<listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

If you want to customize you login form, why you don't extend this filter: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter

Answer (score -3):

Use request.getParameter("j_username"); instead of request.getAttribute("j_username");

It works for me.  See if it helps you.