# How to access previous SOAP headers in SoapInterceptor?

Tags: spring, soap, http-headers

Here's my configuration:

A request is captured by my REST controller, I send data via SOAP to my webservice. Then I access some data sending SOAP request to another service and I return gathered data to the user sending the request.

Before sending SOAP request to external webservice I need to set some headers, so I have an interceptor that extends `AbstractSoapInterceptor` with `Phase.PRE_PROTOCOL` in constructor by webservice side.

Inside `handleMessage()` I create new headers and add to `SoapMessage` but... the data I need to set is inside REST request inside it's headers. So in order to get them I need to have access to `HttpServletRequest` and then I just get the header using `HttpServletRequest#getHeader("header_name")`.

I've saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18211864/accessing-httpsession-in-preprocessinterceptor) I could just use @Context annotation but it's not available in my Spring (3.0.5) or maybe RESTEasy is something else and that question isn't connected with mine in anyway

I've tried this:

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) message.get(AbstractHTTPDestination.HTTP_REQUEST);
```

and

```
ServletRequestAttributes attributes = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
HttpServletRequest request = attributes.getRequest();
```

but it's been a shot in the dark and it failed.

Edit:

Thanks to [Abel ANEIROS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14686836/1873995) I've added:

```
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
```

and was able to get `HttpServletRequest` from `RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()` but apperently it's origin is from my webservice and not REST

Edit2:

The structure is different than I thought.

It's: Rest Controller -> MyWebService (SOAP) -> ExternalService (SOAP)

I've created another interceptor in controller side, added headers to SOAP message and now I'm trying to get the headers again in MyWebService side.